# Phonegap/Xcode issues with iPad 1 app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cordova, ipa

I'm having issues getting an iPad app to work on iPad 1.

I have gotten the app to successfully deploy and install on my iPad 2's but installing the app on iPad 1 doesn't work. The app seems to install, but the icon dissappears after completion. After restarting the iPads the icon reappears, however when opening the app the splash screen pops up then the app closes without any error appearing.

The app is a simple HTML5 & JS app created with phonegap and I currently have other iPad 1's running this app. The iPad 1's running the app currently was packaged by an external dev who has dissappeared but I'm working from his source code. I was told that phonegap dropped ios 5.1 support as of version 3.5 so I also tried rolling back my phonegap version to the latest version of 3.4. I have also tried playing around with some settings such as the build architectures.

My app is for in-house enterprise use, not for the App Store.

---

**Useful information:**

iPad iOS version: 5.1.1 (9B206)

Phonegap version: 3.4.0-0.20.0 / 4.1.2-0.22.12

Xcode version: 6.1

Xcode iOS deployment target: 5.1.1

Architecture: Standard - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Valid Architectures: armv6, armv7, arm64

App is a basic HTML5 app

I'm working with the source code of a fully working live version currently on my iPad 1's

---

**I have also attempted:**

Architecture: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT)

Valid Architectures: armv6, arm64

**Error: No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 arm64).**

Architecture: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT) armv6

Valid Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT) armv6

**Causes Xcode crash when exporting app - has 3 dependency analysis warning at archive stage**

---

**Debugger output:**

2015-01-12 16:50:27.316 MyApp[227:707] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/305DAE80-626C-4CD9-AB47-0139F97B731D/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/305DAE80-626C-4CD9-AB47-0139F97B731D/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

---

Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated. If you require any additional information please let me know.

Comment: Plug the iPad with USB, and in Xcode, open the Windows > Devices menu. Select the iPad 1 on the left, and at the bottom of the window there should be a console with logs giving you more infos on what is going on. Try to reinstall the app while keeping an eye on the logs.

Comment: @Guillaume Algis Xcode doesn't have an iPad 1 simulator AFAIK

Comment: Yep, plug your *real* iPad 1 in USB, an the device will appear in the list.

Comment: @Guillaume Algis Apologies for that Guillaume, I've added the errors from the output. The app crashed after splash screen like when running normally.

Comment: Scan through [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=_objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy). You may find some helpful info on that error.

Comment: @rmaddy Unfortunately of the few questions that the search gives, the majority of the questions have no answers. The ones that had an answer and the question was relevant, I've checked it against my settings and already had the settings in the answer given.

Comment: create a new project with cordova 3.4 or earlier and try again, cordova 3.5 removed iOS 5 support, and as you reverted back, maybe something wasn't reverted correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue myself, despite the lack of responses from any help forums (including the apple developer forum). So I'll try to give a noob-friendly answer, as I feel this is something severely lacking.

iPad 1's have a maximum iOS version of 5.1.1, and do not support 64 bit apps.

To build for iOS 5.1.1+ (iPad 1) compatibility on a phonegap app, set the deployment target for the project, and the target to 5.1.1 (you will need to manually type in). (Swap between project and target by clicking the dropdown on the right in below image)

[image]

Then click on the Project navigator icon on the left side of the image above. In your sidebar you should have your project files, including your config.xml, www folder etc. In this list you should see a CordovaLib.xcodeproj folder.

[image]

This project file defaults to a deployment target of iOS 6.0, changing the target to iOS 5.1 will make the static library CordovaLib compatible with your iPad 1's.

Now, on to building and archiving the app. As iPad 1's don't support 64 bit apps, using the $(ARCHS_STANDARD) for the Architectures option under Build Settings, will cause your app to fail to install on iPad 1.

To fix this remove the option by double clicking on the 'Standard' label, on the Architectures and replace the '$(ARCHS_STANDARD)' with **armv7**.

Now set the option 'Build Active Architecture Only' to **Yes**. You should now be able to leave the 'Valid Architectures' setting to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) - (will display as armv7 arm64). This setting will force the app to build as armv7. Allowing the app to build with arm64 (64 bit) will cause the app to fail to download/install when distributing.

Your app should now install on iPad 1.

---

If you have any issues with the app icon dissappearing after installing, yet reappearing after rebooting the iPad 1 then ensure that the bundle identifier in your project file is the same the bundle identifier in your config.xml in the main folder of your project.

This is caused by the bundle identifiers not matching in those two files.